# How to poll several endpoints sequentially with rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to achieve the following with Rxjs: given an array of job ids, for every id in the array, poll an endpoint that returns the status of the job. The status can be either "RUNNING", or "FINISHED". The code should poll jobs one after the other, and continue the polling until the jobs are in the "RUNNING" status. As soon as a job reaches the "FINISHED" status, it should be passed downstream, and excluded from further polling.

Below is a minimal toy case that demonstrates the problem.

```js
const {
from,
of,
interval,
mergeMap,
filter,
take,
tap,
delay
} = rxjs;
const { range } = _;

const doRequest = (input) => {
  const status = Math.random() < 0.15 ? 'FINISHED' : 'RUNNING';

  return of({ status, value: input })
    .pipe(delay(500));
};

const number$ = from(range(1, 10));


const poll = (number) => interval(5000).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => {
    return doRequest(number)
  }),
  tap(console.log),
  filter(( {status} ) => status === 'FINISHED'),
  take(1)
);

const printout$ = number$.pipe(
  mergeMap((number) => {
    return poll(number)
  })
);



printout$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

It does most of what I described; but it polls all endpoints simultaneously rather than one after another. Here, roughly, is the pattern I would like to achieve:

```
starting with ids: [1, 2, 3]
polling: await request 1 then await request 2 then await request 3
then wait for n seconds; then repeat
after job 2 is finished, send request 1, then send request 3, then wait, then repeat
after job 3 is finished, send request 1, then wait, repeat
after job 1 is finished, complete the stream
```

I feel that in order to achieve the sending of the requests in sequence, they should be `concatMap`ed; but in the snippet above that's not possible because of the interval that would prevent each polling stream from terminating.

Could you please advise how to modify my code to achieve what I am describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, I would proceed like this.

First of all I would create a `poll` function that returns an Observable which notifies after a round of pollings, and it emits an array of all numbers for which the call to `doRequest` returns `'RUNNING'`. Such a function would look something like this

```
const poll = (numbers: number[]) => {
  return from(numbers).pipe(
    concatMap((n) =>
      doRequest(n).pipe(
        filter((resp) => resp.status === 'RUNNING'),
        map((resp) => resp.value)
      )
    ),
    toArray()
  );
};
```

Then what you need to do is to recursively iterate a call the `poll` function until the array emitted by the Observable returned by `poll` is empty.

Recursion in rxjs is obtained typically with the `expand` operator, and this is the operator which we are going to use also in this case, like this

```
poll(numbers)
  .pipe(
    expand((numbers) =>
      numbers.length === 0
        ? EMPTY
        : timer(2000).pipe(concatMap(() => poll(numbers)))
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

A complete example can be seen in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vp3wy7?file=index.ts).

**UPDATE**

If the objective is to notify the job ids which have finished with a polling logic, the structure of the solution remains the same (a `poll` function and recursivity via `expand`) but the details are different.

The `poll` function makes sure we emit all the responses of a polling round and it looks like this:

```
const poll = (
  numbers: number[]
) => {
  console.log(`Polling ${numbers}`);
  return from(numbers).pipe(
    concatMap((n) => doRequest(n)),
    toArray()
  );
};
```

The recursion logic makes sure that all jobs that are still with "RUNNING" status are polled again but then we filter only the jobs which are FINISHED and passed them downstream. In other words the logic looks like this

```
poll(start)
  .pipe(
    expand((responses) => {
      const numbers = responses.filter(r => r.status === 'RUNNING').map(r => r.value)
      return numbers.length === 0
        ? EMPTY
        : timer(2000).pipe(concatMap(() => poll(numbers)));
    }),
    map(responses => responses.filter(r => r.status === 'FINISHED')),
    filter(finished => finished.length > 0)
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: responses => console.log(`Job finished ${responses.map(r => r.value)}`),
    complete: () => {console.log('All processed')}
  });
```

A working example can be seen in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dtugad?file=index.ts).

Comment: Ooh, this is interesting. Looking at the example on Stackblitz, I think it's doing almost what I want it to do; only the subscriber to the whole rxjs pipeline is receiving the running jobs, whereas what I am after is for the pipeline to output finished jobs, one by one, as they get finished. Could you possibly modify your example to show how you would do this?

Comment: You need just to add some `tap` here and there (at least, if I understand your question). [This version of the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vp3wy7?file=index.ts) should show a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite what I meant. I was trying to build a pipeline that takes job ids as an input, and streams finished jobs as an output. It polls all the jobs (one after another), picks the ones that are finished, sends them down the pipeline, and polls the status of the remaining jobs again. Your pipeline takes job ids as an input and streams running jobs as an output.

Comment: I think, at least I hope, I understand. I have updated the response. A [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dtugad?file=index.ts) should show what you are looking for.

Comment: Yay! Now it does what I wanted it to do. I'll play with your solution a bit more.

Comment: One thing I discovered much later while adapting your solution to my code was that returning a `timer` observable from `expand` means that the timer doesn't automatically get cancelled if the outer observable is cancelled. I am a bit at a loss as to how to also properly wire cancellation into this.

Comment: What do you mean by *the outer observable is cancelled*? Do you mean that if you unsubscribe the subscription the time emits anyways?

Comment: > Do you mean that if you unsubscribe the subscription the time emits anyways?

— Yes, this is what happens in my tests. Granted, I am using this stream inside of redux-observable, and then stopping the redux-observable epic with `takeUntil`; but it should amount to the same thing as just unsubscribing.

Comment: What about placing the `takeUntil` as the first operator in the pipe attached to the `timer`, like in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jwxcd2?file=index.ts)?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** Original answer was not on the right track.

What we want to achieve is that on each go around of the interval we poll all the outstanding jobs in order. We yield up any completed jobs to the output observable and we also omit those completed jobs from subsequent polls.

We can do that by using a [Subject](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subject) instead of a static observable of the job IDs. We start our poll interval and we use [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom) to include the latest list of job IDs. We can then add a `tap` into the output observable when we get a finished job and update the Subject to omit that job.

To end the poller interval we can create an observable that fires when the array of outstanding jobs is empty and use [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeUntil) with that.

```
const number$ = new Subject();
const noMoreNumber$ = number$.pipe(skipWhile((numbers) => numbers.length > 0));

const printout$ = interval(5000).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(number$),
  switchMap(([_, numbers]) => {
    return numbers.map((number) => defer(() => doRequest(number)));
  }),
  concatAll(),
  //tap(console.log),
  filter(({ status }) => status === 'FINISHED'),
  withLatestFrom(number$),
  tap(([{ value }, numbers]) =>
    number$.next(numbers.filter((num) => num != value))
  ),
  map(([item]) => item),
  takeUntil(noMoreNumber$)
);

printout$.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.log('COMPLETE'),
});

number$.next([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
```

The other tweak I would make is to use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap` inside the poller itself. If you use that in combination with [`fromFetch`](https://rxjs.dev/api/fetch/fromFetch) for performing your HTTP calls then, if there is some long-running HTTP call which gets stuck, on the next poll the previous call will be cancelled before it makes the next HTTP call because `switchMap` disposes of the previous observable before subscribing to the new one.

Here's a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gxrrb3?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.js

Generates console output looking like this...
[image: example console output]

Comment: Mmm, the example that you provided starts polling for the next job only when the previous job has been finished. That is not the behaviour I was after. I wanted to poll all of the unfinished jobs, only I wanted the polling requests to be sent sequentially rather than in parallel (think chain of promises rather than Promise.all), then to pass the jobs that have finished downstream and to poll the unfinished jobs again after a brief pause.

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated my example so it does that... https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gxrrb3?file=index.js

Comment: Oh, so close! But I think there's a bug in the code. If you inspect what comes out of the `printout$` stream, you will notice that the last finished job does not get through. I piped `printout$` into a `tap(console.log)` to be sure I am not missing something. Nope, the last job gets lost.

Comment: Ah, yes, the takeUntil needs to move up to above the `number$.next()`

Answer (score 0):

TRY this

```ts
import { delay, EMPTY, from, of, range } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, filter, mergeMap, tap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const number$ = from(range(1, 3));

const doRequest = (input) => {
  const status = Math.random() < 0.15 ? 'FINISHED' : 'RUNNING';

  return of({ status, value: input }).pipe(delay(1000));
};

const poll = (jobs: object[]) => {
  return from(jobs).pipe(
    filter((job) => job['status'] !== 'FINISHED'),
    concatMap((job) => doRequest(job['value'])),
    tap((job) => {
      console.log('polling with................', job);
    }),
    toArray(),
    tap((result) => {
      console.log('curent jobs................', JSON.stringify(result));
    }),
    mergeMap((result) =>
      result.length > 0 ? poll(result) : of('All job completed!')
    )
  );
};

const initiateJob = number$.pipe(
  mergeMap((id) => doRequest(id)),
  toArray(),
  tap((jobs) => {
    console.log('initialJobs: ', JSON.stringify(jobs));
  }),
  concatMap(poll)
);

initiateJob.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.log,
  complete: () => console.log('COMPLETED'),
});
```